# SSIS - Get list file names and store into variable object

Tags: variables, ssis

Hi I have csv file into one location, I am using a package that has a forearch loop container, get I put foreach file enumeador, and checked name and extension, then I went to variable mapping and put my  filename variable. Then I have a filenamelist variable as object datatype, what tool I can use to fill my filenamelist (object) with each filename?

path

users/abc.csv
users/azd.csv

get filenames into single variable
abc.csv, azd.csv, ...

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the Foreach File Enumerator works

> Then I have a filenamelist variable as object datatype, what tool I can use to fill my filenamelist (object) with each filename?

In the Variable mapping tab of the Foreach Enumerator, you provide a variable that will hold the *current* value of the enumerator.

In your sample, you have two files in the users folder: abc.csv and azd.csv

The ForEach (File) Enumerator has the smarts to ask the operating system what files match the given file mask (*.csv) that are in the source folder (users). That full list is not available to you as the assumption is you need to perform a task on each item in sequence.

You likely want an SSIS Variable of type String called `CurrentFileName` which you would then use where you have `filenamelist`

The first iteration through, the value of CurrentFileName would be users/abc.csv and you would then add Tasks into the container e.g. a data flow task to load data and then a successor of File System Task to archive the file to a different folder.

The next iteration through, the value of CurrentFileName becomes azd.csv and all the same tasks would be applied but with a new value.

A common misstep is wiring up the value of CurrentFileName into the appropriate Connection Manager so that the source/target file changes in a Data Flow.

### No, I really wanted a list

If you really need to store a list of values, then the datatype of object is correct. What you're then looking for is to write your own Script Task (C# or VB.NET) that generates the list of files and assigns it to the Variable's value. Assuming you have selected User::filenamelist as a read/write variable, that code is approximately

```
// TODO: replace users with actual path
string directoryName = @"users";

// TODO: is this a valid filter?
string fileExtension = "*.csv";

// Instantiate the directory object
System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directoryName);

// Change the SearchOption to AllDirectories if you need to search subfolders
System.IO.FileInfo[] legacyArray = directoryInfo.GetFiles(fileExtension, System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

// Assuming all is well, assign back to the SSIS scoped variable
// This is case sensitive so be wary
// Ensure you assign to the Value property as shown
Dts.Variables["User::filenamelist"].Value = legacyArray;
```

The Task completes, the SSIS Variable filenamelist is populated with values - now what? You can't really do much with a object data type in SSIS beyond ensuring it's not null. However, you can use that variable as the source for a Foreach Enumerator but this time, instead of File, you'd change it to...something with Variable in the title, maybe Variable Enumerator?

Comment: If I've misinterpreted your question on both fronts, we can take another tilt at getting an actionable problem statement